# Store records from Access database in array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

Is there a way I could get records from a MS Access database, and store them in a single array?
I am also open to any suggestions on how to do this another way, if easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arrays have static sizes, I decided to use a list of strings instead, since all field types in my database except for the primary key were set to Text. My code was as follows (in case anyone cares):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader
Dim sqlString As String
Dim path As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & _
        Server.MapPath("database.accdb")
Dim lstRecords As List(Of String)

Sub page_load()
    lstRecords = New List(Of String)
    Try
        dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(path)
        dbConnection.Open()
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM table"
        dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)
        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While dbReader.Read()
            lstRecords.Add(dbReader("record1") + "," + dbReader("record2"))
        End While
        dbReader.Close()
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```